# Why is /proc/net/nf_conntrack empty?

Tags: netfilter, ip-conntrack

On my RHEL 6.5 I expected `/proc/net/nf_conntrack` to contain the latest/current connections but it is completely empty:

```
[root@plop ~]# cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack
[root@plop ~]#
```

Can you help me understand why?

NB: I checked that `nf_conntrack` module is installed:

```
[root@plop ~]# lsmod | grep nf_conntrack
nf_conntrack_ipv6       8748  2
nf_defrag_ipv6         11182  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
nf_conntrack           79758  2 nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state
ipv6                  317340  28 sctp,ip6t_REJECT,nf_conntrack_ipv6,nf_defrag_ipv6
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to enable `nf_conntrack_ipv4`:

```
[root@plop ~]# modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4
[root@plop ~]# lsmod | grep nf_conntrack
nf_conntrack_ipv4       9506  0
nf_defrag_ipv4          1483  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_conntrack_ipv6       8748  2
nf_defrag_ipv6         11182  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
nf_conntrack           79758  3 nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state
ipv6                  317340  28 sctp,ip6t_REJECT,nf_conntrack_ipv6,nf_defrag_ipv6
```